# Read int from process memory

Tags: c#, memory, process, offset

I'm reading data from the memory using a base adress and some offsets:

```
public static int ReadInt(long address)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[sizeof(int)];
    ReadProcessMemory(pHandle, (UIntPtr)address, buffer, (UIntPtr)4,
                      IntPtr.Zero);
    return BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer, 0);
}
```

I add offsets like this:

```
var one = MemoryHandler.ReadInt((long)MemoryHandler.base_adress + 
                                (long)0x0945BB0C);
var two = MemoryHandler.ReadInt(one + (long)0x28);
var three = MemoryHandler.ReadInt(two + (long)0x214);
var four = MemoryHandler.ReadInt(three + (long)0x38);
var five = MemoryHandler.ReadInt(four + (long)0x7EC);
var six = MemoryHandler.ReadInt(five + (long)0x230);
```

Where `six` contains the value that I need.

I tried to make an overload that does the very same thing. My problem is that it's not giving me the same value. I would like to know why:

```
public static int ReadInt(long address, int[] offsets)
{
    long prev = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < offsets.Length; i++)
    {
        address = prev > 0 ? ReadInt(prev + (long)offsets[i]) : ReadInt(address);
        prev = address + offsets[i];
    }

    return (int)address;       
}

var offsets = new int[] { 0x28, 0x214, 0x38, 0x7EC, 0x230 };
var result = MemoryHandler.ReadInt((long)MemoryHandler.base_adress + 
                                 (long)0x0945BB0C, offsets);
```

Just to clarify: I want `result` to have the same value as `six` above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that this will only work on 32bits

```
public static int ReadInt(long address, int[] offsets)
{
    address = ReadInt(address);

    for (int i = 0; i < offsets.Length; i++)
    {
        address = ReadInt(address + (long)offsets[i]);
    }

    return (int)address;       
}
```

You have `offsets.Length + 1` `ReadInt`(s) to do, one without offset and `offsets.Length` with offset. Each one returns the address for the next one. The last one returns a value.

Considering this will work only on 32 bits (because you are reading 32 bits and using them as a ptr), using `long` is useless. `int` is enough.